# How to query for a string in java jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

i am getting below exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?http://www.andhrabhoomi.net/' at line 1
```

I am trying to check whether a string exists in my data base or not

MY CODE:

```
               sql = "SELECT url FROM data where url = ?"+ "string";
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                System.out.println(rs);
```

Comment: resulting `sql` becomes `SELECT url FROM data where url = ?string`, which is not valid ("?string" is not a part of SQL grammar nor a literal)

Comment: Are you using Statement or PreparedStatement? Please go through :

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_prepared_statement.htm

Comment: also if you were doing it the bad way above, the string would need to be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

Since you do have `?` parameter marker, it would appear that you were attempting to use `PreparedStatement`, as you should, all assuming that the `"string"` is a sanitized example of an actual value to be used where `?` is.

This is how a `PreparedStatement` should be done:

```
String sql = "SELECT url FROM data where url = ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, "string");
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("url"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: my code :  

String url1 = " asssa";
sql = "SELECT url FROM data where url = ?";
          PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
          stmt.setString(1, url1);
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
          
          while (rs.next()) {
              System.out.println(rs.getString("url"));
          }

Comment: Remove `sql` from the `executeQuery()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this on your try block

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT url FROM data WHERE url = '?' + string");
ps.setString(1, THE VARIABLE ON WHERE YOU ARE GETTING THE VALUE OF URL);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```